# How to define a jQuery object with noConflict()?

Tags: object, get, response, jquery

Is it possible to define an object $response without the $?

My code will look something like this:

```
jQuery.get("test.pl", { action: "getNextID" }, function(data) {
  var $response = jQuery(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no functional difference between `$response` and `response`. `$` in jQuery is nothing magic, just a reference to `jQuery`; also, using `$variable` in jQuery script is nothing more then a pattern which denotes jQuery object-likeys.

Answer (score 0):

you can call it whatever you wish. the $ prefix is usually just a convention to denote which objects are of the jquery wrapper type (to differentiate them from DOM elements/primitive types). Makes life a bit easier, but won't have any affect on whether you have `noConflict()` on or not

Answer (score 0):

`$response` is just a variable name that happens to start with a `$`. It has nothing to do with jQuery. You can call the variable anything you like - with or without a `$`.